# Como realizar en Blender un cilindro, con varios segmentos a partir de datos en una archivo csv?

Tags: python, csv, script, color, blender

Estoy intentando realizar un cilindro que contenga varios segmentos, estos deben estar con colores, segun codigo, las profundidades se obtienen de un archivo csv.

```
inicio, fin, code
0, 25 , A
25, 50, B
50, 100, A
100, 115, B
115, 150, A
```

Para ello he realizado a partir de un circulo, el cual lo he extruido segun los datos de csv. usando un ciclo for.  Los datos de x,y,z, y diametro estan dado como variables

```
import bpy
import csv

Lit = [] #anida los datos del archivo .csv

#leyendo data.csv
archivo = ('archivo.csv')
with open (archivo, 'r') as csvfile:
    archivo = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in archivo:
        Lit.append(row)

#coordenadas del circulo
_X = 100
_Y = 50
_Z = 120

#colores 
A = ('0.198,0.8,0.085,1')
B = ('0.8, 0.009, 0.010, 1')


INCLINACION = 45

INC = ((90-INCLINACION)*0.436332)/25

DIAMETRO = 2

for fila in range(1, len(Lit)):
    inicio = float(Lit[fila][0])
    prof = float(Lit[fila][0])-float(Lit[fila][1])
    print(prof)
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(radius= DIAMETRO, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(_X, _Y, (_Z-inicio)), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"use_normal_flip":False, "use_dissolve_ortho_edges":False, "mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, (prof)), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.material.new()
    bpy.data.materials["Material.003"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (Color)
```

y hasta el momento he logrado lo que aparece en la figura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder obtener la textura a partir del script como deberia ser el codigo?

una vez obtenida la textura, cual seria el codigo para poder cambiar el centro de pivote, segun coordenadas_X, _Y, _Z, una vez unido los cinco tramos?

Comment: Veo un montón de verborrea, pero no he visto ninguna pregunta. Tampoco he visto nada de código, ni un error... cuál es el problema? Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a [ask] y al [tour]

Comment: gracias por la observacion